# Match horizontal size of dropdown with the textbox size

Tags: html, css

I would like to set the size of the dropdown same as the textbox above it to maintain consistency. Please refer to [this](http://jsfiddle.net/msbUM/21/) fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get it here: http://jsfiddle.net/msbUM/22/

add 
select {width:155px;}​​​​​​
input[type=text] {width:150px;}
​ to your style

Comment: Sorry it is not working in that fiddle, the sizes arent the same.

Comment: Thanks! This version looks better! However, after clicking on the drop down, the sizes of the options are a bit more. How can we fix this?
I am using Firefox v11.

Comment: i think that you can't control, it depends on the content in options